# Student Internship Project: Automate download of report from webpage that does not have API support

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, httprequest

Summary of the project as a whole: I am a student learning app development, this project is for my internship, and I am making an improved schedule for a local small business. They use a 3rd party website for clients to make appointments, but the 3rd party site has a terrible schedule design/ui, so I am making a mobile version for their employees to use. The website does not have any API support but it does allow you to download raw files (reports) that have all the information, but it requires a login to access.

My problem: how do I get my application to login, navigate to, and download the desired file. I can manually download the file and parse the information just fine, but I need this to be an automated process when the app starts or when the user tries to reload the data. I understand this is more of a concept question but I'm trying to be as specific as possible. I'm not really sure where to start with this. Maybe I should ask multiple questions.

All of these processes should be automated (no input required from user)

1) How do I enter login credentials to a website from my app as a background process? (this is a typical text entry login)

2) How do I navigate to the "reports" section of the website after this is done? (simulated button click? not sure what else this is called)

3) How do I download the desired file? (simulated button click)

Again, all of this should happen in the background when the app loads. So the user opens the app, the app finds the file(s), downloads them, parses them, and displays the information for the user.

What I've tried: I have tried to do some research but I'm not really sure what to research in order to answer these questions. I have a basic understanding of CRUD but I feel like this goes beyond that a bit.

What I need: Keywords and topics to research. I tried looking up "swift automated login" "swift automated website navigation and download" but its not really telling me anything. If you have a link to a similar problem and solution that would be amazing, but I am very lost right now.

Comment: This is not the best forum for this type of question.  My advise, take a look at the network traffic with chrome developer tools or charles proxy or any of the like, and then try to replicate some of the calls with postman.  Then come back here and ask specific questions to the issues that you're having while you're providing code that you have tried.

Comment: I have used postman for some API work in class, i did not consider using it for this problem, thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check out WKZombie, a Swift framework for iOS/OSX whose functionality may be just what you need. It describes itself as a headless browser, a web browser without a graphical user interface.

https://github.com/mkoehnke/WKZombie

From the description, its use cases include:

- collecting data without using an API
- automating interaction with websites

Hope this helps. Good luck with your coding project :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will definitely check that out.